# Prove that $\langle x^3 + x + 1 \rangle$ is maximal in the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm assuming that there is an ideal properly containing this generated ideal and trying to show that this ideal contains $1$ and thus is equal to the $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$. I've been multiplying various polynomials times $ax^2 + bx + c$ which is an element in $A$ but not in the generated ideal. So far I can't isolate any sort of constant. Can someone give me a hint? A general strategy?

Comment: The polynomial is irreducible.

Comment: [Here's a tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset math on this website.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, how do we know that?

Comment: @goblin:  A quadratic or cubic is irreducible over a field iff it has no zeros in the field. In our case, we only need to check whether $0$ or $1$ are zeros of $x^3+x+1$, simple substitution.They aren't.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, I see. And does this not hold for quartics?

Comment: @goblin: No it doesn't. For example, $(x^2+x+1)^2$ has no roots in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ but is certainly not irreducible. The reason it works for quadratics and cubics is that if a polynomial of degree $2$ or $3$ factors, at least one factor has degree $1$, so is $0$ somewhere.

Comment: Does anyone see how a constant can be shown to be an element of the ideal properly containing the generated ideal? I appreciate the help. Using a constant as mentioned as above doesn't require me to appeal to theorems we haven't covered yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Fact:* Let $k$ be a field and $p(x) \in k[x]$ be a polynomial of degree $2$ or $3.$ Then $p(x)$ is reducible if and only if $p(x)$ has a root in $k.$

Here $p(x) = x^3+x+1, k=\mathbb Z_2.$ We have $p( 0)= 1$ and $p(1)=1.$ So $p(x)$ has no root in $\mathbb Z_2.$ Hence it is irreducible. Now $\mathbb Z_2[x]$ is a PID and so the ideal $\left< p(x)\right>$ is a maximal ideal.